# PathTech DLLs (ptobjctx, tracelog)

Tags: dll, vb6

A legacy VB6 app I maintain has dependencies on some third-party DLLs. DLL information (from embedded metadata) is pasted below.

I am looking for any pointers to documentation, a current vendor who supports these DLLs, or any tribal knowledge at all about what they do.

[image: ptobjctx.dll] [image: tracelog.dll]

Comment: I presume you've Googled 'PathTech Software Solutions' and found the details that show they are/were based out of Jacksonville, Florida? But as there is no website that I can see they've probably ceased trading. Chances are that there is no support for their products unfortunately.

Comment: @Slugsie Unfortunately nothing in Google searches I could think of turned up anything useful about these DLLs. The links with "PathTech" in them were as you say either secondary and/or not clear if they even were related.

Comment: Do you see anything useful in VB6's Object browser - that at least should tell you the interfaces and methods supported? Or there's always OleView https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx